# Understanding COALESCE in postgres

Tags: postgresql, coalesce, postgresql-9.6

Precise question.

```
Table ROW
value1 a
value2 b    
value3 null
value4 d
```

Function parameters

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "GetValues"(
  "@value1"                   VARCHAR(50),
  "@value2"                   VARCHAR(50),
  "@value3"                   VARCHAR(50),
  "@value4"                   VARCHAR(50)
)
BEGIN
  RETURN QUERY SELECT(
      t."value1",
      t."value2",
      t."value3",
      t."value4",
  )
  FROM "table" as t
  WHERE t."value1" = COALESCE("@value1", c."value1")
  AND t."value2" = COALESCE("@value2", c."value2")
  AND t."value3" = COALESCE("@value3", c."value3")
  AND t."value4" = COALESCE("@value4", c."value4");
END;
```

If I use the above function and only provide the following:

`('a', null, null, 'd')`

It will return `[]` even if 'a' and 'd' are found and I found that this only happens if I provide a parameter to search for something that is `null` and the value of the row is also `null`.

**OLD DESCRIPTION BELOW**

I have setup a get which uses `COALESCE` successfully to search by multiple or 1 parameter(s). However, if any one of those params that are not provided (so default to NULL) are actually NULL in the db because I haven't updated that field before, then it will always return an empty array, even though one of the provided params will successful match to a row in the table.

I just want to know if I need a new system all together to complete this search or if it is just an unfortunate effect of `COALESCE`?

Below is the relevant snippet.

```
  FROM "table" as t
  WHERE t."value1" = COALESCE("@value1", c."value1")
  AND t."value2" = COALESCE("@value2", c."value2")
  AND t."value3" = COALESCE("@value3", c."value3")
  AND t."value4" = COALESCE("@value4", c."value4");
```

In the above, if I provide value1 and it matches but value4 is NULL in that row, then it will return [].

The return is a table with each of those 4 values.

Comment: Can you provide the schema for the relevant tables/columns, and an indication of what output you expect?

Comment: `COALESCE(A, B, C, ...)` gives the first parameter which is not `NULL`. If all given parameters are `NULL` then the function returns `NULL` too. That's how `COALESCE` works. But I really do not understand your problem. Please provide an example or a more precise explanation.

Comment: The return is a table, RETURN TABLE("a" VARCHAR(50)... etc.) and COALESCE works as it does. The issue is with the queried rows. If "@value1" = c."value1" while "@value4" = NULL and c."value4" = NULL because that part of the row is empty, it will return [] even though the first query returned a match.

Comment: My current idea that I have, which isn't desirable, is to add a default value for all values (I hvae another table that has 29 rows, so it isn't ideal).

Comment: @S-Man I have created a precise question

Comment: c. was a typo so I changed it to t. It is the variable for the TABLE. The example content of the table is at the top where it says Table ROW, per field 1-4 a, null, null, d

Comment: Your syntax for the function seems to contain some errors. So it does not have a return type or the braces after the `SELECT` e.g. I created a fiddle as I understood your setup: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=144cb75faa65851c46857577153b6d6d But it is not clear to me what `c` stands for. If `t`is a typo what should it be?

Comment: My bad, c was supposed to b t, t is the Table `from table as t`. It was partially sudo code because the actual create is very long (29 returns, 13 params).

If I simplify the code to only search for a few parameters I know it will return the correct row(s). However, when there are `null` values within rows for one of the search params, it fails. I hope I explained myself adequately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
  FROM test as t
  WHERE ("@value1" IS NULL OR t."value1" = "@value1")
  AND ("@value2" IS NULL OR t."value2" = "@value2")
  AND ("@value3" IS NULL OR t."value3" = "@value3")
  AND ("@value4" IS NULL OR t."value4" = "@value4");
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=0d53249c9cb98b91b51889dbe657805f)

Comment: This is perfect. I am still getting used to postgres and seeing ways like to get check IF something without wrapping it in an IF is a big hurdle for me to grasp.

Answer (score 2):

Should this be a simple row comparison (*give out all rows which have the same values as the input parameters*)?

This could simply be achieved by the row comparator ([documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-comparisons.html#ROW-WISE-COMPARISON)):

```
WHERE row(t.*) IS NOT DISTINCT FROM row("@value1", "@value2", "@value3", "@value4")
```

[demo: db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=b6a866ee2e6f72660fe8cded53eca71a)

If `NULL` as function input parameter should be a wildcard then @kurkle's solution works well.